# QTPass setup in 16.04

Tags: password

I have installed QTPass GUI, now need a tutorial to set it up, is there a link to do that somewhere?

Shakesbeer, with thanks to all.

Comment: You will find documentation for many applications in Ubuntu on the `manpages` and in your case at [ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/qtpass.1.html](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/qtpass.1.html)

Comment: I should add at-least a basic tutorial to the manpage .  .

Answer (score 1):

If anyone would like to help us out, we are looking for some help in the documentation department.
Any kind of help is welcome here.

There are some good `pass` tutorials out there though.

http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/manage-passwords-from-command-line-with.html

https://wetechgeeks.wordpress.com/2016/03/10/manage-passwords-from-the-command-line-with-pass-2/

These apply to QtPass the same.

```
gpg –list-secret-keys
```

Note your keyID . .

```
pass init keyID
```

Is all you'll need to know to get started.

QtPass should guide you through these steps with a wizard at first start (if `pass` / your password-store is not setup properly yet and) even if you don't have GPG set up . .

When using `pass` already you should feel right at home instantly.